Performance problem with Visual Studio 2022 and Bitdefender
I have been experiencing a massive performance issue in Visual Studio 2022 Professional (Version 17.10.4) for a few weeks now. When I create a new project, it takes 01:28 minutes, whereas with Version 17.9.3, it only took 00:10 minutes.
A colleague discovered that the Bitdefender module 'AntimalwareOnAccess' is causing this delay. She tried setting my Visual Studio project folders as exceptions in Bitdefender for monitoring, but unfortunately, it didn’t help. The performance only significantly improves when 'AntimalwareOnAccess' is disabled.
Of course, we do not want to compromise the security on our PCs and are looking for a solution to this problem.
Thank you very much for your help!"
